# VisualBrush in DataTemplate doesn't redraw

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, visualbrush

I have a ListView to display attachments and each attachment has a delete button. When I change the ItemSource for the list (i.e. when viewing another item that has different attachments), the icon for the delete button no longer draws.

Here's the template

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="attachmentListData">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0">
                    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Path=filename}" TextDecorations="{Binding Path=deleted, Converter={StaticResource deletedStrikethroughConverter}}"  />
                </Label>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=deleted, Converter={StaticResource attachmentDeleteButtonVisibilityConverter}}" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Width="40" Height="40" Click="onDeleteAttachmentClicked">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="15" Height="15">
                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_close}" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I've been able to work around the issue by having the appbar_close icon drawn somewhere else in the screen, but having the visibility set to hidden. If the icon isn't somewhere else in the screen, after I change the ItemSource the icon will stop drawing.

Obviously this workaround is hacky, but what is the better way to ensure that the icon still shows up?

Comment: have you tried using x:Shared=False on appbar_close?

Comment: I just tried setting x:Shared to False on appbar_close and that works, but it seems this opens me up for some performance issues down the road since the icon isn't being reused, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the DataType property on the DataTemplate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx. I'd be surprised if this was not giving you a binding error on the line where you're binding button Visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can set x:Shared=False in appbar_close and also you should use [PresentationOptions:Freeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970057.aspx), [RenderOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.aspx) for performance.

Hope it helps.